# Proving formula for feedback for operational amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier

Positive and negative feedback circuits : let the following circuit
[image]

I want to prove that this system is stable (meaning the op-amp isnt getting saturated) if and only if \$ k_+ = \frac{R_{1+}}{R_{1+}+R_{2+}} < k_- = \frac{R_{1-}}{R_{1-}+R_{2-}} \$
Here is what i tried to do, since \$ V_s = A_0 \varepsilon , \varepsilon = V_+ - V_- = k_+ V_s - k_- V_s = V_s(k_+ - k_-)\$ but i dont know how can i relate the saturation to the difference between the two k-factors

**Response for Andy**
For a standard inverting amplifier, we have \$i_- = -i_s \iff \frac{V_-}{R_1} = \frac{V_s}{R_2} \iff V_s = \frac{-R_2}{R_1}V_- \$

Comment: As it is drawn, R1 and R2 form a Schmitt trigger, as it is positive feedback. This will saturate the output.

Comment: hey sparky, thanks for your insight, i dont understand which R1,R2 pair are you talking about, infinite thanks :) @Sparky256

Comment: The ones connected to the + input. Omit them if you want normal op-amp behavior. The - input sets the gain based on the ratio of R2/R1.

Comment: ah yes i understand that i should omit the resistances at the (+) terminal, but the problem asks when the presence of both feedbacks, the k+ should be inferior to the k-, and it asks for a proof.  @Sparky256

Comment: in general, crudest model = write it out for a voltage gain of A, and then take lim A->infinity.

Comment: to check if the equilibrium (ie differential input being 0) is stable, check derivatives of the differential input vs output

Comment: @PeteW omg this is getting abit complex i guess, here is the voltage gain : \$V_s =A_0 V_s (k_+ -k_-)\$

Comment: right, that just lets you solve for the equilibrium tho

Comment: i think everyone in this thread is abit confused, i mean by stability, the behavior of the op-amp in normal state, (not being equal to plus/min saturation voltage), otherwise, if what @PeteW is leading me to the same thing im looking for, then the equilibrium is \$k_+ = k_- \$ no?

Comment: I mean, really, the opamp output is an integrator (with saturation and limited gain, but neither of those will come into play near the balance point). That will actually make it more clear, but it might be more than the question requires to prove stability / derive a stability condition

Comment: so we find that the differential input is zero if the two factors are equal, but im trying to prove one is less than the other @PeteW

Comment: The \$\epsilon = 0\$ condition is just the location of the equilibrium point. Equilibriums can be stable or unstable or saddle points. You can use calculus to classify them. That's the sortof abstract approach. It's also common sense. If a slight departure from equilibrium point results in the system pushing you further away, then it's unstable. If it pushes you back to the equilibrium point, then it's stable

Comment: I wish if we could discuss this further, one question please and it would be enough, 1°) what is the equation to take the derivative of to study the stability of the system. @PeteW

Comment: @PeteW Ah i see, since \$ \varepsilon = V_s (k_{+} - k_-) \iff  \frac{ d \varepsilon}{d V_s} = k+ - k_- \$ the system is stable only if the derivative is negative no?

Comment: I think so, but this type of question is about getting the formalities just right (tho that really depends)

Comment: can you tell me more why should the derivative be negative for the system to be stable? @PeteW

Comment: Or if you model opamp like \$V_s = \int A (V_{+}-V_{-})dt\$, then it comes out even more clearly

Comment: but to previous comment - why should that derivative be negative for system to be stable....  here the \$\epsilon\$ would represent a departure from equilibrium , so the derivative in your expression represents whether you're getting returned to the balance point (when negative) or pushed away from it (when positive). But that might be fudging it. I'm actually not sure if you really need the part about it being an integrator to make it a really solid proof

Comment: but an op-amp isnt an integrator , otherwise i totally understand your idea great explanation ! @PeteW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to prove that this system is stable*

If you were deriving the gain equation for a standard inverting op-amp you would recognize that the inverting input is ideally at the same potential as the non-inverting input and, that is still true for your circuit up until the point at which positive feedback exceeds negative feedback.

So, assume that inverting input voltage equals the non-inverting input voltage and all will come clear.

---

**EDIT (as requested by OP and alluded to above but simpler)**

Consider the [non-inverting op-amp](https://homework.study.com/explanation/what-is-the-difference-between-the-inverting-and-noninverting-amplifiers.html) and my amendment on the right: -

[image]

Notice that \$V_P\$ is now derived from \$V_{OUT}\$: -

$$V_{OUT} = V_P\left(\dfrac{R1+R2}{R2}\right)\hspace{0.5cm} = \hspace{0.5cm}V_{OUT}\left(\dfrac{R4}{R3+R4}\right)\left(\dfrac{R1+R2}{R2}\right)$$

This is manipulated to: -

$$V_{OUT}\left[1 - \left(\dfrac{R4}{R3+R4}\right)\left(\dfrac{R1+R2}{R2}\right)\right] = 0$$

So, \$V_{OUT}\$ will remain stably at 0 volts unless R1, R2, R3 and R4 form a composite value (within the square brackets above) that equal unity (at which \$V_{OUT}\$ becomes indeterminate). To show this more clearly, we can make the simplification that \$R3+R4 = R1+R2\$. Then we are left with R4 and R2 as independent values: -

$$V_{OUT} \left[1 - \dfrac{R4}{R2}\right] = 0$$

So, if R4 is the same value as R2 we have equal values of positive and negative feedback and the result for \$V_{OUT}\$ is indeterminate. If R4 is less than R2 we have the stable case of \$V_{OUT}\$ remaining at 0 volts.

If R4 is slightly less than R2 (and we have a real circuit with noise and offsets), we can see that \$V_{OUT}\$ will start to acquire significantly more noise and offsets.

Comment: ah hello andy, i just wish if you could mathematically express what you want me to do to attain the point where i see that the positive feedback exceed the negative feedback, thanks

Comment: Can you do this for a standard inverting amplifier? If so, please add it to your question as a recognizable new section at the end. Then I'll help you take it to the full circuit in your question.

Comment: Yes i did it now

Comment: Not quite enough; you need the formula to include the voltage at the non-inverting input (call it v+) as an independent signal to the system. Then you replace that with the potential divider from the output to finish the job off. Sorry for not being explicit enough.

Comment: but the voltage at the non-inverting input is basically zero since its linked to the ground no?

Comment: Assume it's at a voltage relative to ground.

Comment: But would it actually matter? because we are assuming we are working with a standard op-amp inverter thus v- = v+ regardless of  what the non-inverting terminal is

Comment: It totally matters if you want to extend it to encompass the general circuit in your question @KnowledgeSeeker

Comment: i think i fail to do that , can you please tell me how the general formula would be?

Comment: Not tonight, it's too late for me now but, send a comment tomorrow for more help

Comment: @Andy aka - it may be that I am wrong (or I did not understand your reasoning), but I do not think that your proof is really logical. This is because you have assumed an IDEAL opamp without any signal voltage at the input - right? Simple counter example:  The output voltage Vout for an ideal opamp with grounded positive feedback only (no input voltage) will be calculated to be Vout=0.  But we know - the circuit will be unstable.

Comment: @LvW I have assumed an ideal op-amp and yes, I have assumed zero volts at the input. Zero volts is valid should the input be a sinewave because it crosses through 0 volts and, we don't have any doubts that the gain equation for a simple non-inverting op-amp is valid at 0 volts as it is for any non-zero-volt level.

Comment: @Andy aka - sorry for the concluding question:  And why is this a proof that negative feedback must dominate?

Comment: @LvW maybe I've been a little presumptive that it was obvious. I shall make an amendment shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some labels to help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8zWqH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The goal is to determine whether the arrangement is stable (negative feedback dominates) or unstable (positive feedback dominates). Formally, we consider if output potential \$V_Z\$ at Z were to be perturbed, how that would change \$V_P\$ and \$V_Q\$, and how those changes would further influence the output.

We assume that the output \$V_Z\$ is related to open loop gain \$A\$ and inputs \$V_P\$ and \$V_Q\$ as follows:

$$ V_Z = A(V_P-V_Q) $$

From that we ascertain that if \$V_P-V_Q\$ were to increase (change towards \$+\infty\$), then \$V_Z\$ also increases (moves towards \$+\infty\$). Conversely, if \$V_P-V_Q\$ decreases (changes towards\$-\infty\$), then \$V_Z\$ will also decrease (change towards \$-\infty\$).

The direction of perturbation of \$V_Z\$ is important, as is the resulting direction of change in \$V_P-V_Q\$. If an increase of \$V_Z\$ would result in \$V_P-V_Q\$ decreasing, that would effectively tend to cancel the initial perturbation, since the output would be changing in a direction *opposing* that perturbation. This would consititute negative feedback, which tends to induce stability.

By contrast, if a perturbation of output \$V_Z\$ causes input \$V_P-V_Q\$ to change in such a way that would push \$V_Z\$ further in the *same* direction, then that is positive feedback, a condition which will result in the output swinging wildly off to some extreme.

To determine which of those two possible conditions prevails, we need to hold potentials \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ steady, at some arbitrary values, and evaluate how \$V_P-V_Q\$ changes as a function of some change in \$V_Z\$. To simplify the algebra, I'll set \$V_A=0\$ and \$V_B=0\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnw0H.png)</sup>

The op-amp's inverting and non-inverting inputs (P and Q) don't draw any current, so the op-amp itself can be considered a voltage source producing \$V_Z\$, but may otherwise be disregarded. The resistors therefore form simple potential dividers between Z and ground.

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_P &= V_Z\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
V_Q &= V_Z\frac{R_3}{R_3 + R_4} \\ \\
V_P - V_Q &= V_Z\left( \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} - \frac{R_3}{R_3 + R_4} \right) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

For negative feedback, stability, you need to show that a change in \$V_Z\$ causes a change in \$V_P-V_Q\$ in the *opposite* direction. In other words, you must show that \$V_Z\$ and \$V_P-V_Q\$ have opposite signs, which I think you can handle from here.

Comment: this is by far the best answer i've seen thanks simon!

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge Seeker was asking:
"*I just wish if you could mathematically express what you want me to do to attain the point where i see that the positive feedback exceed the negative feedback*"

The answer is simple- just write down the closed-loop gain for Ve2=0 (your first diagram) using the **feedback factor (two portions) Hfb=-R1/(R1+R2)+R3/(R3+R4).**
(As you see, I have used another notation for the positive part of Hfb).

With **input damping** (forward factor) **Hfw=-R2/(R1+R2)** the closed-loop gain is

**Acl=(Hfw * Aol)/(1 - Hfb * Aol)** and

**Acl=-Hfw/Hfb** for Ao approaching infinity.

Therefore (after inserting Hfw and Hfb):

**Acl=+[R2/(R1+R2)]/{[R3/(R3+R4)]-[R1/(R1+R2)]}**

(For R3=0 the above equation reduces to the known gain of an inverting opamp Acl=-R2/R1).

As you can see, when the positive feedback portion R3/(R3+R4) in the denominator exceeds the negative portion, the resulting gain Acl would be positive. However, this is a **contradiction** to the expected negative closed-loop gain Acl.
Therfore, we always require **R3/(R3+R4)<R1/(R1+R2)**